# Add the output of a command to the bookmark via \addcontentsline

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, bookmarks

I would like to add the result/value/output of a command into ToC, via `\addcontentsline{toc}`. The output by itself only contains pure text, so in principle it should be allowed to be presented even in the bookmark hyperlink.

Below is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{projlib-datetime}
\begin{document}
% \tableofcontents\bigskip
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\TheDate{2023-01}}
\end{document}
```

Ideally the output `January 2023` should be presented in the bookmark, but now I am getting the warning:

```
Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)  removing `\TheDate'.
```

I suppose that there might be some issue of expansion, but is there some way to overcome this so that the final output can be successfully put into the bookmark?

Answer (score 1):

`projlib-datetime` defines `\TheDate` as protected macro. Because of this, the macro persists, when generating the bookmark text. `hyperref` warns in such cases and just removes the command.

What you need is an expandable `\TheDate`. You can use such a command in general or only inside the bookmark generation using `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{projlib-datetime}
\newcommand*{\monthname}[1]{%
  \ifcase #1 \or 
    January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
    July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or
    December
  \fi
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\theYearMonth[1]{\@theYearMonth#1\\}
\newcommand*{\@theYearMonth}{}
\def\@theYearMonth#1-#2\\{\monthname{#2} #1}
\makeatother
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \let\TheDate\theYearMonth
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\TheDate{2023-01}}
Test
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\theYearMonth{2023-02}}
Toast
\end{document}
```